# search specific number in iphone contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I am developing a Voip application. My application has its own call logs and screen is same as native call logs. Application also has its own contacts received from server and also has iphone contacts option which display iphone's contacts like Skype.

Problem :
If any contact suppose "9999999999" is stored in native contacts i.e. in iphone contacts. It will be stored as "99-99-999999" in iphone. Now suppose incoming call in my application comes from "+919999999999" number (means with country code).
My app should find name for that number and display it. And call log detail screen should display all information which is stored in iphone's contacts (like photo, multiple number, etc.)
To search name for number I have used [**This**](http://hesh.am/2012/10/lookup-a-contact-name-using-phone-number-in-abaddressbook/). But given method in like compares exact number (not compare number with or without country code).

Is there any API available ? 
I don't know how it is possible because "Bria" and "Viber" application does this.

Any help....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just hardcode the list of all country codes and check against each country?

Comment: I know they didnt had an api for this 1,5 year back. also the numbers (format) are dependent on localizing settings

Comment: I don't know how other applications did this.